# How to fix RPError: nonce mismatch, expected xxxxx, got: undefined" error using casdoor OIDC

Tags: oauth-2.0, oauth, openid-connect, directus, openid-provider

I've integrated Casdoor login with directus using openid connect and there is a problem in login flow. When user is authenticated on casdoor side, it redirects to redirect_url with `code` and `state` query params and on callback stage, directus decodes `JWT` and it cannot find `nonce` in the payload and it throws the error:

```
nonce mismatch, expected xxxxxxxxxxx , got: undefined
```

I modified directus image to disable the nonce check and after that it worked fine but I know that's a dangerous thing to do and it's not a workaround. So I wanted to know why casdoor is not adding `nonce` in the payload.

This is how my login request looks like:

```
https://casdoor.local/login/oauth/authorize?client_id=<CLIENT_ID>&scope=openid%20email%20profile&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdirectus.local%2Fauth%2Flogin%2Fcasdoor%2Fcallback&access_type=offline&code_challenge=<CODE_CHALLENGE>&code_challenge_method=S256&state=GqOMoe4GOjBlFxCBPpKb0GAzzshZVNH_NHpZcO1lTiw&nonce=GqOMoe4GOjBlFxCBPpKb0GAzzshZVNH_NHpZcO1lTiw
```

And this is how my callback looks like:

```
https://directus.local/auth/login/casdoor/callback?code=<CODE>&state=GqOMoe4GOjBlFxCBPpKb0GAzzshZVNH_NHpZcO1lTiw
```

I also decoded the JWT returned on callback using online decoder https://jwt.io/ and saw that it doesn't contain any `nonce` value. Is it something to do with my login request to ask for `nonce` in response? or could it be the bug on casdoor side?

JFI, I'm using latest versions of both casdoor and directus and my directus env variables are following for integration with casdoor:

```
PUBLIC_URL: ${PUBLIC_URL}
AUTH_PROVIDERS: ${AUTH_PROVIDERS}
AUTH_CASDOOR_DRIVER: ${AUTH_CASDOOR_DRIVER}
AUTH_CASDOOR_CLIENT_ID: ${AUTH_CASDOOR_CLIENT_ID}
AUTH_CASDOOR_CLIENT_SECRET: ${AUTH_CASDOOR_CLIENT_SECRET}
AUTH_CASDOOR_SCOPE: ${AUTH_CASDOOR_SCOPE}
AUTH_CASDOOR_ISSUER_URL: ${AUTH_CASDOOR_ISSUER_URL}
AUTH_CASDOOR_AUTHORIZE_URL: ${AUTH_CASDOOR_AUTHORIZE_URL}
AUTH_CASDOOR_ACCESS_URL: ${AUTH_CASDOOR_ACCESS_URL}
AUTH_CASDOOR_PROFILE_URL: ${AUTH_CASDOOR_PROFILE_URL}
AUTH_CASDOOR_ALLOW_PUBLIC_REGISTRATION: ${AUTH_CASDOOR_ALLOW_PUBLIC_REGISTRATION}
AUTH_CASDOOR_DEFAULT_ROLE_ID: ${AUTH_CASDOOR_DEFAULT_ROLE_ID}
```

Comment: I've submitted a PR to directus with the fix to this problem: https://github.com/directus/directus/pull/21418
In case someone is also facing the same issue, you can pull the fix and rebuild your directus image to fix this until they merge this PR.